# Unable to upload pdb files django

Tags: django, python-2.7, pdb-files

I am creating an application, where users can upload files. The issue is users are able to upload any file with any file format except "pdb" file format.
Here is my source code:

```
def pdb_upload(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        data = request.POST
        pdb_files = request.FILES.get("uploaded_pdb", None)     
        handle_upload(pdb_files)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/?path=%s' % (download_path,))

def handle_upload(f):
    with open('media/input/'+str(f),'wb+') as  destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

Comment: What web server do you use? Are there any errors in the log?

Comment: I am using the default django web server and there are no errors in the log.